# Java awt SystemTray - Popmenu too small on Surface 4 Pro

Tags: java, awt, retina-display

We've a Java application with a trayicon (SystemTray) and a popup menu (PopupMenu) that worked nicely on all platforms.

On a new Surface 4 Pro we've a problem as the size of the menu is amazingly small. Looks as not noticing it's a 'retina'/high definition display.

Is there an easy way to fix this ?

[image]

Comment: Is the font issue application-wide or is it limited for SystemTray elements?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you may have to resort to setting the menu UI.

See : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#setUI-javax.swing.plaf.PopupMenuUI-

Of course that means you need some way to determine that you're running on the Surface Pro in the first place.

You could try figuring out the current font size and dimensions used by the menu UI and compare that with the screen dimensions from `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()`

Comment: The question references AWT, however answer uses Swing.  Are you sure it'll work?

Answer (score 2):

As a general solution, which is not tied up to specific devices, you could detect  screen resolution in dots-per-inch via:

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution()
```

This will return screen resolution **in DPI (dots-per-inch)**. The bigger this value - the smaller the textual fonts will get for a specific font size.
Use the DPI to set an acceptable (or maximal) DPI settings and calculate the adjustment ratio.

You can adjust either by replacing the UI delegates fonts (for an application-wide effect)
OR, if the issue is specific for the system-tray, by deriving a larger font only for SystemTray's MenuItems:

```
java.awt.Font defaultFont = java.awt.Font.decode(null); // default font 
float adjustmentRatio = 1.0f; //  Calculate this based on your metrics
float newFontSize = defaultFont.getSize() * adjustmentRatio ; 
java.awt.Font derivedFont = defaultFont.deriveFont(newFontSize);

// PopupMenu with the adjusted font size: 
MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Menu Item");
item.setFont(derivedFont);
popupMenu.add(item);
```